# How to improve Solr query performance?

Tags: solr

I am new to solr and using solr 4.7 to obtain text based search. My solr is having single collection with uniquely indexed field. I am facing performance issue for search query. I am thinking to add either multiple core on single solr instace or multiple instance with replicated data.
please help me which option i need to choose to improve solr performance.

Can anyone suggest me whether it will increase my search query performance by adding master-slave configuration. where Master will take care of all commits and slave will take care for search-query.

Comment: Have you get any progress in performance for search query? Please, if you have done then assist me. I am in same trap.